# After installing .net 3.5 SP1, get missing DLL error

Tags: .net, gac

I just installed a number of updates to my machine, and am now encountering the following error when I run an asp.net MVC application on my local machine:

Compiler Error Message: CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINNT\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll' could not be found

I have removed the reference to this from the project (not really sure why it was there in the first place) but still get the error.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

It turns out that something had installed the DLL from .net 1.1 into the GAC.  The solution was to find the correct version of the DLL, and register it with:

```
gacutil /if System.EnterpriseServices.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post:

Possible workaround if .NET Framework setup hangs while registering System.EnterpriseServices.dll

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/01/08/510677.aspx

Its speaks to .NET 1, 1.1, and 2.0, but where 3.5 still uses the 2.0 BCL, it MAY apply.